# How to add items to an array while looping through it?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

On a `foreach` loop, it seems PHP reads the whole array at the beginning, so if you suddenly need to append new items to the array they won't get processed by the loop:

```
$a = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

foreach ($a as $b)
    {
        echo " $b ";
        if ($b ==5) $a[] = 11;
    }
```

only prints out:  `1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just create a reference copy of the array you are looping

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$t = &$a; //Copy
foreach ( $t as $b ) {
    echo " $b ";
    if ($b == 5)
        $t[] = 11;
}
```

Or Just use `ArrayIterator`

```
$a = new ArrayIterator(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
foreach ( $a as $b ) {
    echo "$b ";
    if ($b == 5)
        $a->append(11);
}
```

Output

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FHXJmo)

Answer (score 2):

On the spirit of [its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), this is the best workaround I have found: convert it to a `while` loop.

```
$a = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($a))
    {
        $b =  $a[$i];
        echo " $b ";
        if ($b ==5) $a[] = 11;
        $i++;
    }
```

Not it properly gives out  `1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11`

Comment: The only poblem with this might be that count($a) is executed every time the loop is run as well which can be a performance hit. I'm not too sure how foreach handles this though.

Comment: You could make the while more compact with for
`for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {`

Comment: @AlexanderVarwijk the whole premise is that the size of $a may change anytime, so counting it at each iteration is the only way to find out

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to create a second array which will keep the old array and while looping you can add new values there .

At the end of the loop the new array will have **the old one + new inserted values**

Answer (score -2):

```
$arr = [1,2,3];

while ($el = current($arr)) {
    var_dump($el);
    $arr[] = 123; // infinite loop
    next($arr);
}
```